# For any prime $p>3$ show that 3 divides $2p^2+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Does anyone know how to show this preferable **without** using modular

For any prime $p>3$ show that 3 divides $2p^2+1$

Comment: I think this is silly. The two (eerrr, three) answers given so far, which *do* use modular arithmetic, are trivially transformed into proofs that do not. I.e., put $p=3k+1$ or $p=3k+2$ and see where this gets you.

Comment: reason to why I don't want modular is because we still haven't come that far in my course.

Comment: I added to my answer a simple proof without using modular arithmetic.

Comment: @user142405, why hobble yourself that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid modular arithmetic, you can easily do the explicit calculations, distinguishing the two cases

- $p = 1 + 3 k$, then $$2 p^{2} + 1 = 2 (1 + 6k + 9 k^{2}) + 1 = 3 (1 + 4k + 6 k^{2})$$
- $p = 2 + 3 k$, then $$2 p^{2} + 1 = 2 (4 + 12k + 9 k^{2}) + 1 = 3 (3 + 8k + 6 k^{2})$$

Comment: why does p=1+3k and p=2+3k?

Comment: Do Euclidean division of $p$ by $3$. The remainder can be zero (which is impossible, as $p \ne 3$), or $1$ (so that $p = 3 k + 1$), or $2$ (so that $p = 3 k + 2$).

Answer (score 4):

Without using mod: note $\, 2p^2+1 = 2(p^2-1)+3\,$ so it suffices to show that $\,3\mid p^2-1.\,$ One of the $\,3\,$ consecutive integers $\,p-1,\,p,\,p+1$ [must be](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/253390/242) a multiple of $\,3$. It cannot be the prime $\,p> 3,\,$ therefore either $\,3\mid p-1\,$ or $\,3\mid p+1,\,$ hence $\,3\mid(p-1)(p+1) = p^2-1\ \ $ **QED**

Using mod, it is easier:  $\,\ 3\nmid p\,\Rightarrow\ {\rm mod}\ 3\!:\ p\equiv \pm 1\,\Rightarrow\, p^2\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\ 2p^2+1\equiv 3\equiv 0 \ \ $ **QED**

**Remark** $\ $ So the result is true for any integer $p$ not divisible by $3$. It's equivalent to the special case $\,q=3\,$ of Fermat's little Theorem: $\,q\nmid p\,\Rightarrow\,p^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod q$

Answer (score 1):

For any prime $p>3$ we have $p\equiv 1\mod 3$ or $p\equiv 2\mod 3$ and in the two cases we have
$$2p^2+1\equiv 0\mod 3$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $p>3$ it holds that $p\equiv 1,2\pmod{3}$. Then $p^2\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ and then $2p^2\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. Adding $1$ yields the result.

Answer (score 0):

**Generalization**:

If $q$ is prime not dividing integer  $\displaystyle m,(m,q)=1\implies m^{q-1}\equiv1\pmod q$ (by Fermat's Little Theorem)

$\displaystyle(q-1)m^{q-1}\equiv (-1)\cdot1\pmod q\equiv-1\iff (q-1)m^{q-1}+1\equiv0\pmod q$

Here $q=3$